# Simple PHP time format not working!

Tags: php, date

I have the following value:

```
30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15
```

I need to convert it to Y-m-d H:i:s.

I've tried:

```
$date = "30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15";
$formatteddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time($date));
echo $formatteddate;
```

I end up with a value dated 1970. I've also tried strtotime.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Look at the 3rd "note" on the [strtotime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) . You definitely will get bad values passing a string to `time()` - `strtotime()` is what you should use.

Comment: @jesse If he uses strtotime() for that string it will not work.

Comment: @Flipper correct. That's why I told him to look at the 3rd note on the  [strtotime() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)  before suggesting he use it.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? A lot of the answers on this page use functions that require PHP > 5.3.0. Keep an eye out for that.

Comment: @Asaph The majority of answers here use strtotime() which is PHP 4+.

Comment: @Flipper: There are several answers based on `DateTime::createFromFormat()` or `date_parse_from_format()`.

Comment: @Dominor Novus Don't forget to choose an answer as the accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function does not have any parameters which is why it is going to give you an error.

I have tried to use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) thinking that may work, but it is not.  I will update my answer when I find something that works.  However, first thing is that time() will not work.

Edit: As Phil just beat me to seconds before:

```
$date = str_replace("@ ", "", "30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15");
$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
$formatteddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
echo $formatteddate;
```

Example is here:  http://codepad.org/heph1PG0

Comment: My original date/time value is generated by jquery date/time picker. Will this be easier to solve if I omit the @ symbol?

Comment: You can view the time formating options for the picker here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @Dominor Novus I just added code to convert the string correctly.

Comment: @Dominor Yes, if you can format the time from the date/time picker into `d-m-Y H:i:s`, then you can easily parse the value with `strtotime()`

Comment: @Flipper: Your code block worked. I'm additionally trying achieve the exact reverse format to output the typical PHP format as the my "quirky" European format with the @ symbol. I was able to manage the string replacement but how do I apply the strtotime? This is what I tried but no cigar: `$date = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime($datetimeofcall));`. I preceded it with `$date = str_replace(" ", " @ ", "$date");` and `$date = str_replace("-", "/", $date);`.

Comment: @Flipper: Done. I was incorrectly preceding the strtotime with the str replace. I can now store my date and time value in my mySQL table in the typical datetime format [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss] but input (via datetime picker) and output (parsed html table) using the non-US format [dd/mm/yyyy @ hh:mm:ss]. I'll append the solution to my question and close the thread off in a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP 5.3, try `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, eg

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y @ H:i:s', $date);
```

If not, `strtotime()` may work but you'll need to get rid of the `@` symbol and change the forward slashes to hyphens (if that's an EU / AU date), eg

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace(array('@', '/'), array('', '-'), $date));
```

**Edit:**

To display the dates in the format you want, use

```
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // for DateTime
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time); // for strtotime
```

Comment: After `DateTime::createFromFormat()` do a `echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Thanks. I'll confirm this in a bit. I'm now trying to reverse the formatting though the strtotime isn't applying as desired. See the comment I left for Flipper.

Comment: I managed to the get the reverse formatting working. I had to apply the strtotime before the string replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of an odd format there... try date_parse_from_format.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

```
$date = "30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15";

$d = date_parse_from_format('m/d/Y @ h:i:s', $date);

$formatted_date = "{$d['year']}-{$d['month']}-{$d['day']} {$d['hour']}:{$d['minute']}:{$d['second']}";
```

Comment: @jesse The `@` symbol is a bit weird though

Answer (score 1):

You have a very odd date format, so `strtotime` will have trouble. Instead we will use `strptime` which accepts a custom format:

```
$date = "30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15";
$format = "%d/%m/%Y @ %T";
$ftime = strptime($date, $format);
$timestamp = mktime( 
                $ftime['tm_hour'], 
                $ftime['tm_min'], 
                $ftime['tm_sec'], 
                // Because this is 0-11
                $ftime['tm_mon'] + 1,
                $ftime['tm_mday'], 
                // Because this is years since 1900
                $ftime['tm_year'] + 1900
             ); 
$formatteddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $formatteddate;
```

Result:

```
2010-05-30 09:15:15
```

Comment: Note, `strptime()` is not available on Windows hosts

Comment: @Phil ugh, after I spent all that time putting that together. I guess I'm better off living a life on the road. *drives off into the sunset on a motorcycle*

Comment: Eek! I just finished implementing and testing this. Moving on (thanks anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.3.0 or greater, you can use [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to parse your custom formatted date.

If you're stuck on an older version of PHP, you'll have to parse it yourself. I've verified that this works:

```
<?php
function reformatDate($date) {
    $matches = array();
    if (!preg_match('/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})\s*@\s*(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$/', $date, $matches)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid date supplied: ' . $date);
    }
    $day = $matches[1];
    $month = $matches[2];
    $year = $matches[3];
    $hour = $matches[4];
    $minute = $matches[5];
    $second = $matches[6];
    if ($day < 1 || $day > 31 || $month < 1 || $month > 12 || $hour > 24 || $minute > 60 || $second > 60) {
       throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid date supplied: ' . $date);
    }
    return "$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:$second";
}

echo reformatDate("30/05/2010 @ 09:15:15");
?>
```

Comment: That regex requires fully validated input. ie, try passing it this: `$date = "42/42/420 @ 42:84:84";`

Comment: @jesse: Good point. Although any of the other answers on the page that use built-in PHP functions will not handle that input any more elegantly. Nevertheless, I will make an attempt to handle that input without complicating my code too much. Hang on...

Comment: @Asaph whoops, didn't mean it like that, just wanted to make the point, not suggest that you attempt to validate w/ the regex.

Comment: @jesse: I made it a little better by enforcing the right numbers of digits in the regex and adding a guard clause. Also turned it into a function. It will still barf on something like `"31/02/2010 @ 09:15:15"` which is nonsense because there are not 31 days in February. But it's an improvement.

Comment: @Asaph Not true; `DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y @ H:i:s", "42/42/420 @ 42:84:84")->format("r") => Thu, 13 Jul 0423 19:25:24 +1000`

Comment: @Phil: I stand corrected. BTW: that function is only available in PHP > 5.3.0. I was offering an alternative solution for those that are stuck with an older version of PHP.

Comment: @Asaph I purposefully didn't show the `mktime()` version which doesn't work (probably because of the year) ;-)

Comment: @Phil: FWIW: I think `DateTime::createFormFormat()` is actually giving the wrong answer in your example. I was curious and double checked this test case in Java with the `Calendar` class which gives `Sun Aug 12 19:25:24 PST 423` for the input `420-42-42 42:84:84`. In Java the `GregorianCalendar` class implements dates to a tee including all the bizarre one-off adjustments that were made over the years before leap years/leap seconds/etc. were invented. More gory details in the javadocs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: @Asaph Ah yes, forgot about all that mess. Even with the timezone difference (what's PST, GMT-7?) it doesn't add up

Answer (score 0):

for all of you guyz date function will not format dates like 01/01/2045, this is something php restriction for dates having large years i.e 2039.

Answer (score -1):

Try Like this...

```
<?php
$date = date_create('01-01-2001');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```